# Not able to create stored procedure in DB2

Tags: stored-procedures, db2

I am trying to create a stored procedure in DB2 using IBM DB2 Cloud. I am getting the error as:

> An Unexpected token 'END-OF-STATEMENT' was found following "".

Detail about the error is seen in the screenshot below.

[Click here for error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wTIMV.png)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE trial_pro(in msg varchar(100))
language sql;
BEGIN
    insert into collision values(msg);;
END
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all:

- There ";" behind language sql is wrong.
- Two ";" after the line with the insert do not make sense and do not match with the screenshot.

In addition to that: While ";" is the statement terminator inside your stored procedure make sure to choose (configure) another one for the (outer) create procedure statement. Usually the tools you run the SQLs offer a option to change it.

Answer (score 0):

You must change the default statement terminator (`;`) if you use a compound statement.
In the DSM console you can do it either temporarily for some particular statement:

```
--#SET TERMINATOR @
CREATE PROCEDURE trial_pro(in msg varchar(100))
language sql
BEGIN
    insert into collision values(msg);
END@
--#SET TERMINATOR ;
```

or set it by default with:

> `Editor options` (gear icon at the top right corner) -> Statement
>   terminator -> @